# Set start value for column with autoincrement

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Orders` with the following fields:

> Id | SubTotal | Tax | Shipping | DateCreated

The `Id` column is set to `autoincrement(1,1)`.

This is to be used in an E-commerce storefront. Sometimes a current E-commerce store is migrated to my platform and they already have orders - which could mean that their current `Order.Id` is, for example, `9586`.

I want to have the `autoincrement` field start from that value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

From [Resetting SQL Server Identity Columns](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ResetSqlServerIdentity.aspx):

Retrieving the identity for the table `Employees`:

```
DBCC checkident ('Employees')
```

Repairing the identity seed (if for some reason the database is inserting duplicate identities):

```
DBCC checkident ('Employees', reseed)
```

Changing the identity seed for the table `Employees` to 1000:

```
DBCC checkident ('Employees', reseed, 1000)
```

The next row inserted will begin at 1001.

Answer (score 29):

You need to set the Identity seed to that value:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
 id int IDENTITY(9586,1)
)
```

To alter an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ALTER COLUMN Id INT IDENTITY (9586, 1);
```

More info on [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)

Comment: The ALTER TABLE command above does not work for me in Microsoft SQL Server 2012. It gives this error:  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'."  The DBCC command in the accepted answer worked correctly though.

Answer (score 11):

Also note that you cannot normally set a value for an IDENTITY column.  You can, however, specify the identity of rows if you set [IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql) to ON for your table.  For example:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders ON

-- do inserts here

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders OFF
```

This insert will reset the identity to the last inserted value.  From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql):

> If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for
>   the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the
>   current identity value.

Comment: just what I was after - was useful for populating a database that I was migrating from a mysql php to a C# MVC app

Answer (score 3):

In the Table Designer on SQL Server Management Studio you can set the where the auto increment will start. Right-click on the table in Object Explorer and choose Design, then go to the Column Properties for the relevant column:

[Here the autoincrement will start at 760](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo2Gt.png)