# How to start identity insert from 1 every finacial year?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table for sales order. In that table i want store bill number.
That bill number identity start from 1 to n number for financial year, After completion of financial year it will start with new bill number,

like start from : 1  to n number.

And that time i want to insert also financial year in a column.

Help me what should i do for achieve this functionality.

For Example:

[image]

Comment: please provide some examples what you want to achieve using examples rather in terms of words

Comment: you may want to check here ,question is still unclear :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Take the total count of bill number in every financial year and increment by one, then save it manually to database, so that you can get bill number from 1to n every year

Comment: Have a look into this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askjay/2012/10/08/sequence-objects-in-sql-2012-and-sql-2008/

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to achieve this with identity, or you can start a new table for every year, could give a better performance

Comment: @ARUN, "Take the total count of bill number in every financial year and increment by one" is a bad solution, as you will have concurrency problems

Comment: @ARUN, I don't want to create new table for the same.I have existing application only i want to change the bill number.
I think Alex is right.

Comment: But it's endless sequence, we can't start over again i think

Comment: If you want to make a change to old data, what will happen, I don't know much finance, whether closed are edited

Comment: @ARUN, That I'll do but first i want solution for this.

Comment: Have a a look at composite key, haven't used it myself

Comment: @Manish Sharma, in my opinion I would not restart bill numbers for each financial year as this may cause confusion. Just let them increase ad infinitum. Storing financial year information next to bill number is enough to allow you to find which bill belongs to which year. You may have other specific reasons for why you want numbers to restart.
The answer provided by Akshey Bhat should work when you have a clearly defined cut over event/time i.e. you allocate all bills entered before this moment to current financial year and then after this moment it is next financial year.

Comment: Because CHECKIDENT RESEED is dangerous I would use a [custom solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419447/how-to-best-generate-a-unique-user-number-without-duplicates-in-a-multi-tenant-d).

Comment: Why do you care what the number is? either it's an internal key, in which case you shouldn't care, or it's a business key, which you should store in a different field. Don't mix them up. Does this requirement come from a reasonable business requirement? What impact will it be if the number for the new year starts at 2? at 10? at 1000?

Comment: Another alternative is to use "sequences table" described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("table name", RESEED, 0);
```

After inserting rows for one financial year run the above script to reset identity column.

Comment: CHECKIDENT RESEED is dangerous. Depending on previous actions, next IDENTITY value could be 1 or 0.

Comment: Next identity value can be zero in case table is truncated that I think is not the case here