# how to set ID start from 10000 or any 5 digit number in SQL and C#?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table called '**users**'.

```
user_id
user_name
user_password
```

The **user_id** column start from 1.
Is there any way to start from 10000 or any 5-digit number?

Note : I user SQL in my C# Program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set start value for column with autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280705/set-start-value-for-column-with-autoincrement)

Comment: And how database is created? Are you using EF Code First? Or any other ORM?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining the table, you can use

```sql
Create Table Users
(
  user_id int IDENTITY(10000,1),
  ...
)
```

or if the table is already defined with rows in it, then you can use

```sql
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, new_value);
```

where new_value is whatever number you need to start with again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.

The primary key of a table should only ensure row uniqueness, and should not convey any information about the data. Its "form" should be of no consequence.

You probably need to ask yourself why do I want specific values? If you want to expose them in the UI, or send it to an external related application, then you may be better off creating a secondary [auto-]generated column just for this purpose. I would strongly recommend you leave the PK alone and don't touch it.

Comment: What if I want to generate 5-digit invoice number like 00001 , 00002 and ...? how to create secondary auto-generated column? Thanks.